# Responsive 4x4 CSS grid

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am having a very hard time creating a responsive CSS grid. For example, this is what I want outputted on desktops:

```
________________________________________________________________________
| Stat 1 | Stat 2 | Stat 3 | Stat 4 | Stat 5 | Stat 6 | Stat 7 | Stat 8 |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Info 1 | Info 2 | info 3 | info 4 | Info 5 | Info 6 | Info 7 | Info 8 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But this is what I want outputted on mobiles:

```
_____________________________________
| Stat 1 | Stat 2 | Stat 3 | Stat 4 |
|------------------------------------
| Info 1 | Info 2 | info 3 | info 4 |
-------------------------------------
| Stat 5 | Stat 6 | Stat 7 | Stat 8 |
|-----------------------------------|
| Info 5 | Info 6 | Info 7 | Info 8 |
 ------------------------------------
```

I have the following HTML and CSS that outputs correctly on desktop but it doesn't output correctly on mobiles.

HTML

```
<div id="statcontainer">
    <div class="stat-header row clearfix">
            <div class="stat-value">
                Stat 1
            </div>

            <div class="stat-value">
                Stat 2
            </div>

            <div class="stat-value">
                Stat 3
            </div>

            <div class="stat-value">
                Stat 4
            </div>

            <div class="stat-value">
                Stat 5
            </div>

            <div class="stat-value">
                Stat 6
            </div>

            <div class="stat-value">
                Stat 7
            </div>

            <div class="stat-value">
                Stat 8
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="stat-content row clearfix">
            <div class="stat-value">
                info 1
            </div>

            <div class="stat-value">
                info 2
            </div>

            <div class="stat-value">
                info 3
            </div>

            <div class="stat-value">
                info 4
            </div>

            <div class="stat-value">
                info 5
            </div>

            <div class="stat-value">
                info 6
            </div>

            <div class="stat-value">
                info 7
            </div>

            <div class="stat-value">
                info 8
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.statcontainer {
    display: table;
}

.stat-header {
    display: table-row;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.stat-content {
    display: table-row;
}

.stat-value {
    display: table-cell;
    border: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why are you using divs when your use case look like it should be using `<table>`? HTML has already a table element ready to use when you need this sort of display.

Second of all, how do you expect to have a responsive layout without using media queries? Media queries are what will make your design responsive. You should always make sure to have your initial layout mobile first, and media queries to display the desktop view. Here would be a simplified version of what you were trying to achieve:

https://jsfiddle.net/n4xoj2ju/

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Stat 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Stat 2
    </td>
    <td>
      Stat 3
    </td>
    <td>
      Stat 4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Info 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Info 2
    </td>
    <td>
      Info 3
    </td>
    <td>
      Info 4
    </td>
  </tr>  
</table><table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Stat 5
    </td>
    <td>
      Stat 6
    </td>
    <td>
      Stat 7
    </td>
    <td>
      Stat 8
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Info 5
    </td>
    <td>
      Info 6
    </td>
    <td>
      Info 7
    </td>
    <td>
      Info 8
    </td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table tr:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) {
  table {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Comment: All the documentation I've read recommends using DIVS with flex for responsive layouts. Is there a reason you recommend using tables?

Comment: Well supportability can be one reason not to use flexbox http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox but I don't understand since your original post was using divs with table CSS properties. Unless you have really good reasons to do this you can simply use a table for tabular data (which again I'm presuming since I'm not sure of your actual use case).

Comment: Using your code, I get a gap between the two tables in desktop view and on mobile, the 2nd table does drop under the first but the tables are too wide for the screen width and cause me to have to scroll to the side to view it. I fixed the second issue by applying width: 100% in the @media call but how can I erase the gap between the two tables in desktop?

Comment: Make sure to put `<table></table>` on the same line. For some reasons HTML can be sensitive to white space and new lines. That's what I did in the jsFiddle to solve this problem. Normally using an HTML minifier before sending the output to the user also help to get rid of these problems.